# Django-ckeditor file upload doesn't work

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-ckeditor

I use django-ckeditor module in my blog as WYSIWYG editor for create and edit articles in the administration. It work pretty well but I can't upload image to my server. When I click on the image button, the button "browse the server" and "upload image" doesn't appear as they supposed to (I saw it somewhere). I can only add externals images providing their urls.
I use Django 1.8 with Python 3.4

The module django-ckeditor and ckeditor_uploader are correctly installed and added in the INSTALLED_APP.

This is my settings.py file :

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django-mini-blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django-mini-blog.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the following code to your urls.py file?

```
    urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    ....
    (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),

)
```

Comment: I have `url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),` in my project urls.py. ckeditor.urls is not recognized, I got an ImportError using it : No module named 'ckeditor.urls'

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Some backward incompatible changes were made in versions after 4.5.1 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor/). I believe that your settings are correct for version 4.5.1 Or change your urls.py to (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))