# installing django apps on ubuntu server gives an AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'

Tags: python, django, git, ubuntu-14.04

i am having hard time installing a django apps on a server using mod_wsgi, i follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04).

I am using django 1.8, python 3.4.3, mysql as SGBD, pip, virtualenv and ubuntu 14.04.

The only change is that i used git to install the project (git clone), manage.py call a different setting files used for a staging environment.

i was able to collect static files and makemigrations everythings goes right, but for testing purpose i tried to load the application using the runserver command but when i trying accessing the website using ipadress:port,  an error occured, here is the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 394, in urlconf_module
    return self._urlconf_module
AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 52, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in __init__
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/project/staging/project/project/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'ckeditor.urls'
[27/Dec/2015 16:45:44]"GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 394, in urlconf_module
    return self._urlconf_module
AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 52, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in __init__
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(None).url_patterns:
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 402, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/project/staging/project/project/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/user/project/projectenvenv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'ckeditor.urls'
```

The projects lives in /home/user/projectName and the user and group are: user:user
It is a bi-language (english and french) apps, it looks like a problem with url config so here is my main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog_article', app_name='blog'))
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (
            r'%s(?P<path>.*)' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:],
            'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}
        ),
    )
```

and the blog.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog.views import index, ArticleDetails, ArticleCategoryList, ArticleTagList
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='blog-index'),
    url(_(r'^details/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'), ArticleDetails.as_view(), name='blog-details'),
    url(_(r'^categorie/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'), ArticleCategoryList.as_view(), name='blog-category-list'),
    url(_(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'), ArticleTagList.as_view(), name='blog-tag-list'),
]
```

i have search a lot and i did not find a clue yet, any help is welcome !

Comment: Do you have installed `ckeditor` module on your server?

Comment: The last exception that's raised is an `ImportError` for `ckeditor.urls`. The other exceptions are irrelevant in this case.

Comment: django-ckeditor is installed on server, but a friend of mine point me to an incompatibility with last version of this module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418190/django-ckeditor-file-upload-doesnt-work. I am investigate it, thanks for you help

Comment: do you think i should change the title of this post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i downgrade django ckeditor to use the one use in my local dev, and every thing looks fine. the version installed on server was the 5.0.2 and some settings (or url needs to be change), see [Django-ckeditor file upload doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418190/django-ckeditor-file-upload-doesnt-work)

thanks for helping me